# Can someone please explain me why can't return a smart pointer?

Tags: c++, smart-pointers

I was wondering what could be wrong with returning a smart pointer. The compiler throws that the constructor itself has been deleted. So I tried with returning the reference and it works, why is this possible?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
using namespace std;

using unique_int = std::unique_ptr<int>;
unique_int p_Int = std::make_unique<int>();

unique_int GetPtr()
{
    return p_Int;
}

unique_int& GetPtrAddr()
{
    return p_Int;
}
```

The error message is

```
function "std::unique_ptr<_Ty, _Dx>::unique_ptr(const std::unique_ptr<_Ty, _Dx>&)[with _Ty=int, Dx=std::default_delete<int>]"(declared at line 3269 of "memory library path") cannot be referenced -- it is a deleted function
```

Comment: Because it wouldn't be _unique_ anymore.

Comment: ...because that constructor has been deleted. Please include the error message as text in the question

Comment: Is that so? It's my first time handlig with this, thanks for the response!

Comment: the only way a copy constructor could not break uniqueness would be by transfering ownership, but it would be bad if the copy constructor would do that. You have to explicitly move the unique pointer to transfer ownership

Comment: related:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16030081/copy-constructor-for-a-class-with-unique-ptr

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67443342/tring-to-create-a-unique-pointer-gives-me-an-error?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Thanks 463035818_is_not_a_number, changed it and so a way to reach with this problem is returning the R-value of P_int?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's examine what would happen when you return a `std::unique_ptr` by value.
`unique_int` function creates a temporary object of `std::unique_ptr` type, for which a copy-initialization of the temporary `std::unique_ptr` from `p_int`, which you return. But the whole point of `std::unique_ptr`, is that it cannot be copied, only [moved](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/move_constructor).

Comment: Thanks this explanation made me clear so basically unique_ptr can exist just one type of itself, but shared_ptr and weak_ptr can have two variables having the same address.

Comment: @Game_dev Yes, you understand correctly.

Comment: @Game_dev • if you need a smart pointer with value semantics, someone made a [`value_ptr`](https://buckaroo.pm/blog/value-ptr-the-missing-smart-ptr) for that purpose.